# How to detect property changes in Windows Runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone

Previously in `Windows Phone Silverlight` apps, we could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise it:

```
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != id)
            {
                id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently, in in default hub template of `Windows Runtime App`, I see we use

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items{ get; set; }
```

It will only detect if an item of collection added or removed, But how about changing an existing item's property?
I change a property of an item, but it doesn't take effect. what is wrong? thanks.

**Update:** I see we still can do that and works. But is it the recommended way to do in Windows Runtime apps?

Comment: Still the same like in WPF.

Comment: The template is just a template. It's not a full-featured implementation of anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `Item` class you want to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in that class. Anything you want to modify to the existing items' property will reflect to the UI by calling `RaisePropertyChanged()` event.

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // Omitted implementation of INPC

  private string _name;
  public string Name { get { return name; } set { _name = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); } }

  public void Update()
  {
     Name = "NewValue"; // This will show up in the UI if it is bound to a property (DataBinding)
  }
}
```